# React Router confusion

Tags: javascript, reactjs, ecmascript-6, react-router

New to react & react-router.

I'm trying to understand this example:

https://github.com/ReactTraining/react-router/blob/1.0.x/docs/API.md#components-1

But this.props never contains main or sidebar. My code:

Main.js

```
ReactDOM.render(
    <Router>
      <Route path="/" component={App2}>
        <Route path="/" components={{main: Home, sidebar: HomeSidebar}}/>

      </Route>
    </Router>,
  document.getElementById('content')
);
```

App2.js

```
class App2 extends React.Component {
  render() {
    const {main, sidebar} = this.props;
    return (
        <div>
          <Menu inverted vertical fixed="left">
            {sidebar}
          </Menu>
          <Container className="main-container">
            {main}
          </Container>
        </div>
    );
  }
}

export default App2;
```

Home.js

```
import React from 'react';

class Home extends React.Component {

  render() {
    return (
      <div><h1>Home</h1></div>
    );
  }

}

export default Home;
```

HomeSidebar.js

```
class HomeSidebar extends React.Component {
  render() {
    return (
      <div>
        <p>I'm a sidebar</p>
      </div>

    );
  }
}

export default HomeSidebar;
```

I'm using electron with react dev tools. Whenever I debug, this.props contains neither main nor sidebar. Any idea why this is happening?

I've also tried using an IndexRoute, but it seems to not support a components prop.

**Other things I've tried**

```
ReactDOM.render(
    <Router>
      <Route component={App2}>
        <Route path="/" components={{main: Home, sidebar: HomeSidebar}}/>
      </Route>
    </Router>,
  document.getElementById('content')
);

ReactDOM.render(
    <Router>
      <Route path="/" component={App2} components={{main: Home, sidebar: HomeSidebar}}>
        <Route path="admin" components={{main: Admin, sidebar: AdminSidebar}}/>
      </Route>
    </Router>,
  document.getElementById('content')
);
```

Comment: I removed my answer about routes having the same path since it didn't help you. But this is how I solved a similar problem some time ago.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you're using the current version of react-router (v4.0.0), it looks like they did away with the components prop on Routes: https://reacttraining.com/react-router/web/api/Route

You can render Routes anywhere, and they even have a [sidebar example](https://reacttraining.com/react-router/web/example/sidebar) where they do just that. They have one set of Route components to render the main components and another set of Route components for sidebars, but both come from a single route config to keep it DRY.

To translate that to your code, you could create a route config:

```
const routes = [
  { path: '/',
    sidebar: Sidebar
    main: Main
  }
];
```

Then in Main.js

```
ReactDOM.render(
    <Router>
      <Route component={App2}>
        {routes.map((route, index) => (
          <Route
            key={index}
            path={route.path}
            component={route.main}
          />
        ))}
      </Route>
    </Router>,
  document.getElementById('content')
);
```

Then in App2.js

```
class App2 extends React.Component {
  render() {
    return (
        <div>
          <Menu inverted vertical fixed="left">
            {routes.map((route, index) => (
              <Route
                key={index}
                path={route.path}
                component={route.sidebar}
              />
            ))}
          </Menu>
          <Container className="main-container">
            {this.props.children}
          </Container>
        </div>
    );
  }
}

export default App2;
```

Comment: Sigh, it looks like this is a case of "I've been reading the outdated documentation". I'm using the latest version, but have been reading what appears to be the 1.0 documentation. Thank you for this, I will try it soon.

Answer (score 4):

Looks like to have the components prop work you need use the `<IndexRoute />` component instead of `<Route />`. In the react-router docs it mentions that IndexRoute has all of the same props as Route so doing

```
<IndexRoute components={{main: Main, side: Side}} />
```

works!

Full code:

```
React.render((
  <Router>
    <Route path="/" component={App} >
      <IndexRoute components={{main: Main, side: Side}}  />
    </Route>
  </Router>
), document.getElementById('app'))
```

Codepen: http://codepen.io/chmaltsp/pen/ZeLaPr?editors=001

Cheers!

Answer (score 1):

The example from github was written 2 years ago (look [here](https://github.com/ReactTraining/react-router/blame/1.0.x/docs/API.md#L193)) and I'am not sure for which particular version it is related. And I'am not sure does it works now (because I am also new with react), but I know that you don't have use this approach to reach this aim, you can use separated component which will contains `mainz` and `sidebar`, here my example:

```
class App2 extends React.Component {
  render() {
    return (
        // Your Menu.
        // Your Container.
        <div>
          {this.props.children}
        </div>
    );
  }
}
class Home extends React.Component {
  render() {
    return (<div><h1>Home</h1></div>);
  }

}
class HomeSidebar extends React.Component {
  render() {
    return (<div><p>I am a sidebar</p></div>);
  }
}
class HomeWithSidebar extends React.Component {
  render() {
    return (
      <div>
          <Home />
          <HomeSidebar />
      </div>
    );
  }
}   
ReactDOM.render(
    <Router history={browserHistory}>
      <Route path="/" component={App2}>
        <Route path="/a2" components={HomeWithSidebar} />
      </Route>
    </Router>,
  document.getElementById('content')
);
```

PS: Don't forget use `<Router history={browserHistory}>` in your example.

 And use `IndexRoute` in your example or specify another, like `/a2` in my example.

Answer (score 1):

Im new to react router myself but I am sure that the routes you are using are incorrect. in the example you give you have 2 different routes that resolve to the same path (/):

```
ReactDOM.render(
    <Router>
      <Route path="/" component={App2}>
      <Route path="/" components={{main: Home, sidebar: HomeSidebar}}/>

      </Route>
    </Router>,
  document.getElementById('content')
);
```

I beleieve this should be something like:

```
ReactDOM.render(
    <Router>
      <Route path="/" component={App2}>
        <IndexRoute components={{main: Home, sidebar: HomeSidebar}}/>
        <Route path="some/other/path" components={{main: Home, sidebar: SomeOtherSidebar}}/>
      </Route>
    </Router>,
  document.getElementById('content')
);
```

Answer (score 0):

I hope you know that you are using react-router 1.0.x and it is quite outdated. Current version is 4.x.

Below code works perfectly( based on your example provided).

```js
let Router = ReactRouter.Router;
let RouterContext = Router.RouterContext;
let Route = ReactRouter.Route;

class App2 extends React.Component {
  render () {
    const { main, sidebar } = this.props;
    return (
      <div>
        <div className="Main">
          {main}
        </div>
        <div className="Sidebar">
          {sidebar}
        </div>
      </div>
    )
  }
}


class Home extends React.Component {

  render() {
    return (
      <div><h1>Home</h1></div>
      
    );
  }

}


class HomeSidebar extends React.Component {
  render() {
    return (
      <div>
        <p>I'm a sidebar</p>
      </div>

    );
  }
}


ReactDOM.render(
    <Router>
      <Route component={App2}>
        <Route path="/" components={{main: Home, sidebar: HomeSidebar}}/>
      </Route>
    </Router>,
  document.getElementById('content')
);
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/15.1.0/react.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/15.1.0/react-dom.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react-router/1.0.3/ReactRouter.min.js"></script>

<div id="content"></div>
```

Comment: You get downvotes because you point some one to think in correct direction.